# Docker+yii2 = Ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: yii2, nginx, docker

Сделал окружение на Docker (php7,nginx,mysql...)
При запуске yii2 получаю такие ошибки:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://findme/assets/5a4c56e3/css/bootstrap.css".
jquery.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
yii.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
bootstrap.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Вот вся сборка с yii2 в public_html
https://github.com/Vladbara705/php-apache-mysql-containerized

Интересует решение этой проблемы.
Так же, при установке yii2 композером нужно вручную задавать папке web/assets права, как решить и это ?
Как при такой конфигурации использовать миграции ?

p.s. пробовал уже официальный образ docker для yii2. Все то же самое. Полагаю, что криво установил docker (или что то в этом духе)

Comment: Суля по сообщениям у вас вместо ассетов приходит html. Скорее всего это страница 404 ошибки. Проверяйте настройки сервера и пути

Comment: @alexeyten именно так. Приходит html. Но куда смотреть уже не знаю.

Comment: Скорее всего у тебя есть файл entrypoint, где прописаны команды апдейта композера, добавь там выполнение init, потому что именно в этом случае устанавливаются права на runtime и assets.

Comment: .env надо бы в гитигнор добавить и логи нет смысла хранить в репозитории.